# Python Numbers mysteriously being rounded on comparison

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was having some problem with Numpy arrays and I stumbled across it, and it confused me.

I'm trying to compare 2 parts of arrays using `array_equal`

```
np.array_equal(updated_image_values[j][k],np.array(initial_means[i]))
```

This is returning `False` when the numbers are

```
[ 0.90980393  0.8392157   0.65098041]
[ 0.90980393  0.8392157   0.65098041]
```

Above is my print of the two arrays.

However, when I print the individual elements one seems to be rounded of for no reason

```
print updated_image_values[j][k][0] #0.909804
print initial_means[i][0]  #0.90980393
```

Then obviously when these individual elements are compared it returns `False`

```
print updated_image_values[j][k][0]==initial_means[i][0] #False
```

Can anyone explain why Python is doing the comparison wrong and for no apparent reason rounding the numbers?

Comment: Floating-point numbers DO NOT REPRESENT AN EXACT VALUE.  Two floats that happen to compare as equal is a coincidence, not something you should test for or rely on.

Comment: Issue a `np.set_printoptions(precision=16)` and compare the arrays again ;-).

Comment: `set_printoptions` works !!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `updated_image_values` has had some operations done on it. And what classes are the numbers?
My guess is that what you're seeing isn't "rounding", it's got something to do with the `__str__` or `__repr__` functions of the classes. The fact that you're seeing 0.90980393 when you print the list means that the element is not really rounded to 0.909804. Try `"{0:.10f}".format(updated_image_values[j][k][0])`.
As for the comparison, you're probably seeing the floating point operations change the value enough that it's outside of the tolerance of `array_equal`. Try using `isclose` [instead](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html#numpy.allclose).

Comment: While `isclose` works `set_printopts` seem more correct